# Can I push data from web to my Ubuntu?

Tags: 10.10, cron

I am trying to do something which involves pushing data to my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop from web (PHP) and somehow I can catch that data. Just like Push emails. Thoughts? Ideas?

I know I can setup a cron job to keep checking for events, but is there anything like PUSH which can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done. Your computer should be running a web server like Apache of any other server which can accept incoming requests. Even your handwritten server, it should be listening to an interface at a specific port.

Now you need to forward that port on your router if you are behind NAT on your router. You can check [Ubuntu Docs for forwarding port](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) and [Manufacturer specific doc](http://portforward.com/)

Then your PHP script needs to connect to your computer by specifying your IP which is visible to outside world. The script should connect to the port which you forwarded otherwise the connection will be dropped at the router itself. Read the [concept of port forwarding on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding)

Comment: @Manish That sounds so logical, I feel dumb. Server will be the client and I will have to be a server. But I don't have a static IP, so I was thinking of letting the server know about my IP regularly making a cron job and then the server can push data to that IP. I hope port forwarding is only about ports and can work here in case of dynamic IPs. Would that work? Also any pointers for building a barebone listener? I might use nginx permanently as I am a web developer and that won't be an overkill but I would like something small that can be passed on to others too.

Comment: or may be pointers about building one will be better as a new question?

Comment: If I understand correctly, port forwarding is just open up ports to listen. Right?

Comment: Port forwarding is a setting up a rule to tell the router that "if you receive a connection request on this port from outside world forward that request to this IP address within the network". More than one computer can be connected to a network. So port-forwarding is sort of `guide` who tells the router what to do when a request comes on some port.

Comment: You can use dyndns.com and run a cron script on your server which tells dyndns.com of your IP address. The client then looks up the your ip address on dyndns.com before connecting. Since all HTTP connections are made on port 80 but default, so one rule in port forwarding is enough.

Comment: @Manish Thanks for explaining & introducing `dynds.com`, it will save a lot of efforts for sure. Any pointers or guides on how do I go about building a simple listener which will listen to the data?

Comment: Building a small webserver will be better as of a new question, so marking this as accepted.